# Qt - QFile not opening a .qss file

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use an external stylesheet for my project and I'm having trouble opening it using the QFile class. I've imported it into the .qrc file, a portion of it looks like this:

```
  <qresource prefix="stylesheets">
    <file>Resources/Stylesheet.qss</file>
  </qresource>
```

This is how I am opening and using the file:

```
QFile stylesheet(":/stylesheets/Resources/Stylesheet.qss");
if (stylesheet.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    newGameDialog.setStyleSheet(stylesheet.readAll());
    stylesheet.close();
}
```

What could be wrong with this? I am using Visual Studio 2013 with the latest Qt and the VS Qt Add-in. I've also set the project to support QML in "Qt Project Settings".
The .qss file looks like this (it works if set directly as a QString). I'm not sure if the "import" line is needed:

```
import Qt 5.3.1

QDialog
{
    background-color: 'white';
}
```

It is reading it fine, but the style is not applying. Here it is in debug mode:
[image: debug]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QDialog does not support "background-color", only "backgroud:".

(Further ideas if that doesnt work:
Maybe forgot to specify Q_OBJECT for newGameDialog class?

Alternatively use Qt Designer to create a QDialog, copy your stylesheet source in the stylesheet property field and see if it works or if the designer shows an error or does apply the style correctly when test-instanciating the dialog (Ctrl+R i think).)

Comment: Q_OBJECT is present. I've removed the "import" line, compiled the .qrc file manually and it works now. When is the "import" line used?

Comment: Haven't seen import up until now, where did you get it?

Comment: Stumbled upon it while searching the Internet for guidance, I guess. I have experience with normal CSS, but not this.

Comment: I think qt's stylesheets are more limited (and also have some expressions specific to qt).

Comment: Do you maybe know how can I programmatically change a value defined in the .qss file. I need to dynamically change the background of the QMainWindow but setStyleSheet is not working. It probably gets overriden by the global one.

Comment: You can progammatically change a value that you've read in from a .qss file by reading the style in to a QString from styleSheet.readAll(). Then you'd have to do pattern matching (maybe QRegexp) to find the class or object name identifier and change the qss in the string to what you want. Then use setStyleSheet with the new string.